# JWT, Using a dynamic secret key stored in DB

Tags: authentication, jwt, express-jwt

**I need some advice about future pitfalls and problems if I go forward with below approach.**

I am using JWT and I need to expire all previous tokens of a user when he/she changes his/her password.

The approach I took to make a unique secret key for each user is concatenation my secret key and user password (`config.jwtSecretKey + user.password`) to generate a dynamic secret key.
Once the user changes his/her password the secret key will change and hence all previous tokens will be invalid.

Things are working fine but to validate each token I need a DB call to get the password.

Please suggest how can I improve this or what is the right way to do the same.

Comment: are you saving your passwords in plain text?

Comment: No, I am using bcrypt to encrypt the password.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is quite good as it's to KISSy

> The database query can be reduced by using some in-memory cache of your dynamic secret key.

Also, you can change the dynamic key from `password hash` to `some random hash` to reduce conflicts. It will reduce a lot of security threats.

Comment: The nice thing of using a dynamic key is that with that hash algorithm you can provide Single Sign-On really quick, even worldwide, but if your algorithm is compromised (e.g. a member of the company) you are screwed or if its just based in the password or data coming from the client a breach on his side can be dangerous as well. IMHO a mix of the two can provide really nice authentication: you just request few fields of the database that can be cached, combined with a quick/unpredictable hash algoritm you can provide a really fast and effective authorization mechanism.